# How to plot this kind of graph in Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

```
Department   left
IT           0       0.777506
             1       0.222494
RandD        0       0.846252
             1       0.153748
accounting   0       0.734029
             1       0.265971
hr           0       0.709066
             1       0.290934
management   0       0.855556
             1       0.144444
marketing    0       0.763403
             1       0.236597
product_mng  0       0.780488
             1       0.219512
sales        0       0.755072
             1       0.244928
support      0       0.751009
             1       0.248991
technical    0       0.743750
             1       0.256250
```

[This graph generated using pandas plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBjs.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBjs.png): [[https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBjs.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBjs.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBjs.png)
it is a multi indexed data frame when we construct a graph in pandas hue is formed. I need exactly the same as in seaborn or pyplot. thank you in advance for ur replies!!

Comment: use `sns.barplot` https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: Give your dataframe in some format. Then only someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that both pandas plotting and seaborn are just an interface to matplotlib. Both matplotlib and seaborn can be used to retouch and extend a pandas plot. E.g. you can apply a seaborn style to such a pandas plot and `plt.title('...')` to set a title.

Next, seaborn prefers to ignore the indices and work with explicit columns, while pandas plotting strongly depends on the indices. You can use `reset_index` to convert both indices to columns.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''Department   left    value
IT           0       0.777506
IT           1       0.222494
RandD        0       0.846252
RandD        1       0.153748
accounting   0       0.734029
accounting   1       0.265971
hr           0       0.709066
hr           1       0.290934
management   0       0.855556
management   1       0.144444
marketing    0       0.763403
marketing    1       0.236597
product_mng  0       0.780488
product_mng  1       0.219512
sales        0       0.755072
sales        1       0.244928
support      0       0.751009
support      1       0.248991
technical    0       0.743750
technical    1       0.256250'''

# create a dataframe similar to the given one
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.set_index(['Department', 'left'])

sns.set_style('darkgrid') # this also works with pandas
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 3))
# use reset_index so seaborn can work with them as columns
sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='Department', y='value', hue='left', ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot for dataframe with double index]